# Selenium-rc: How do you use CaptureNetworkTraffic in python

Tags: python, selenium-rc

I've found many tutorials for selenium in java in which you first start selenium using `s.start("captureNetworkTraffic=True")`, but in python `start()` does not take any arguments.

How do you pass this argument? Or don't you need it in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed the `start` in `selenium.py`:

```
def start(self, captureNetworkTraffic=False):
    l = [self.browserStartCommand, self.browserURL, self.extensionJs]
    if captureNetworkTraffic:
        l.append("captureNetworkTraffic=true")
    result = self.get_string("getNewBrowserSession", l)
```

The you do:

```
sel = selenium.selenium('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', 'http://www.google.com')
sel.start(True)
sel.open('')
print sel.captureNetworkTraffic('json')
```

and it works like a charm

Comment: What is the `*firefox` part?

Comment: But i am getting error `NameError: global name 'captureNetworkTraffic' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Start the browser in "proxy-injection mode" (note `*pifirefox` instead of `*firefox`). Then you can call the `captureNetworkTraffic` method.

```
import selenium
import time

sel=selenium.selenium("localhost",4444,"*pifirefox","http://www.google.com/webhp") 
sel.start()
time.sleep(1)
print(sel.captureNetworkTraffic('json'))
```

I learned the `*pifirefox` "trick" [here](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/bfbadd4c285091b3).

Comment: But does this method work without starting the driver with "captureNetworkTraffic=true"? Meaning unlike Java, etc. this method or feature in Python will be "always on"?

Comment: @David: Instead of `captureNetworkTraffic=true`, I found I needed to start the browser in proxy injection mode. (see above)